# How to use ob_start() in PHP project while using of Front Controller pattern

Tags: php

How can I use `ob_start()` in my PHP project when I use Front Controller pattern? I mean I just want it for some files in my project not all files.

My `index.php` something like this and I want to use `header(location:)` redirect in `register.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once("../base/initialize.php");

switch($path)
{
    case '/':
    case '/index.php':
        require_once(MAIN_PATH.DS.'index.php');
        break;
    case '/user/register.php':
        require_once(M_USER_PATH.DS.'register.php');
        break;
    case '/user/login.php':
        require_once(M_USER_PATH.DS.'login.php');
        break;
```

Comment: You just have to make sure you use it before you print any content.

Comment: @Ibu tanks for answering. I thought it means that I have to use ob_start() in the beginning of index.php. but I found that it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my fault. I thought `ob_start()` must be the first thing in pages (like `session_start()`), but it's not necessary, you just put it before sending header.

So i put it before my header layout in `register.php` and redirection is done well.